# I want to cover the onBlur event in javascript by writing JEST test case in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, jsforce, lwc-jest

In my html component i've used an onBlur attribute in div. While writing the test case for the same i am unable to cover the javascript method which I've called in html.
My div looks like this

```
<template>
    <div class="container" onBlur={onBlurEvent}>
       ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Js:

```
onBlurEvent(){
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: `div` elements don't receive focus by default, so you can't register an `onblur` event unless you first add `tabindex="0"` or `contentEditable` ([see StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function)).  Without this, I'm not sure your function will execute in a browser, let alone in Jest.

*Side note: the convention here is to use lowercase `onblur` vs. camel-case `onBlur`, although both technically will work.*

Now more to the point: I have had success calling `blur()` in Jest on an element that has focus.  If your element is able to receive and lose focus, you should be able to do this:

```js
let container = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div.container');
container.focus();
container.blur();
```